# How to build a very customerized layer in Keras for this purpose?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, layer

I have a high frequency time series data that I want to fit into a CNN network for identification work.  However I need to decide which frequency I would want to look at, so a typical way to do it is :

```
time_step = 10
A = cumsum(input_data)
B = A[0 : len(A): time_step].
C = B[1:] - B[:len(B)-1]
```

,which samples at every 10 time points.

However, I wonder if I can make a Keras customer layer that the time_step is a parameter of the network?   So that the network would tell me what is the optimal value for **time_step** parameter.

Comment: Could you please explain what is the sampling rate within this context? Is the idea about selecting timepoints separated by p timesteps?

Comment: @rvinas  Yes I want the network to learn the optimal interval P.